# creating more forms after exporting MS Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have MS Access 2007 database with forms and tables, until now i did not know that size limit of a access database is 2 GB.

So if export the access database to SQL server express using upsizing tool, will the forms be migrated or can i still use access database for form interface, while keeping sql express for storage. Otherwise do i need to create those forms again?

Answer (score 1):

You can retain your access database just as it is but instead of having your tables in a MSAccess database you have them as linked tables from SQL Server.

Check out http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Linking-SQL-Express-2005-Tables-to-MS-Access-2007/

or http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Comment: Can you please direct me to a place where i can learn how to do this?